# Woocommerce - Place product excerpt after Tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd need to place the product excerpt from below the rating below the Product Tags section. I changed the priority from 20 to 41 and placed the code the functions.php of my child theme.

From Woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php

```
/**
         * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
         */
```

In my Functions.php I tried:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 41 );
```

The excerpt doesn't change place and it's still under the rating.

Comment: This is because your theme has some specific related customizations, you need to search/ask in your theme support pages.